# Python simple ini writing

Tags: python

In Delphi I can write 3 essential lines to write Str variable to ini file.

```
with Tinifile.create('a.ini') do
try 
  WriteString('sec', 'name', Str) 
finally 
  Free 
end;
```

In Python I see not nice module ConfigParser (Py 2.x) which needs creating object, creating section, then writing value, then writing ini.... not nice!

Maybe simple ini handling class exists?

Ini must be usual for Windows:

```
[sec]
name=data_str
name2=data_str_2
```

Comment: Is there anything that makes your ini file any different from a normal text file?

Comment: Nope. usual INI file for Windows XP.

Comment: I can see 6 lines of Delphi with all the boilerplate. ConfigParser is trivially easy to use. I don't see a problem. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm sure you can write a wrapper function that creates a section and writes a value in one call if that's what you think is missing.

Comment: @interjay yeah, but that's not a solution - its simply syntax sugar.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why is it not a solution? It's what programming is all about.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Isn't that exactly what he's asking for?

Comment: See @DavidHeffernan's comment, I don't want to repeat what he said.

Comment: Maybe right, can use a wrapper for configparser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Delphi code is almost exactly what is available in Python. I can see two differences:

1. In Delphi, you are doing multiple write statements for each line, in Python there is only one.
2. In Python, you have to define the section explicitly.

In fact, the [example from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) is almost exactly what you have posted:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section('sec')
config.set('sec', 'name', 'foo')

with open('a.init', 'w') as f:
   config.write(f)
```

Comment: Thanks man. i can use maybe such code too.

Comment: It's odd that you accepted this. I mean, the code here is the canonical way to write an ini file. It's just that this code does everything that you seemed to be railing against. I suspect I don't understand your question.

Comment: @David. I mean I can use suggested code for my wrapper. my wrapper yes, needs to be simple. I didn't see  off example.

Comment: But this is the example from the documentation.